# añadir un espacio en php

Tags: php

buen dia soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo quisiera saber como hago un espacio en esta fila

```
$sub_array[] = $row["uNombre"]. $row["uApellido"];
```

ya que cuando imprimo me sale pegado el nombre con el apellido

Comment: `echo $unacosa . " " . $otracosa;`

Comment: También en esta ¿pregunta? habría que preguntar: ¿qué has investigado? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes! solo te falta concatenar un espacio en blanco entre ambos, así:

```
$sub_array[] = $row["uNombre"] . " " . $row["uApellido"];
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer asi

```
   $sub_array[] = $row["uNombre"]." ". $row["uApellido"];
```

Comment: Hola andy, esta respuesta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin ninguna explicación de qué es lo que hace dicho código o cómo soluciona el problema, se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para los demás usuarios. Lee [answer] y edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Con esto lo tienes resuelto.

```
$sub_array[] = $row["uNombre"]." ".$row["uApellido"];
```

Comment: Hola Oswuell, esta respuesta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin ninguna explicación de qué es lo que hace dicho código o cómo soluciona el problema, se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para los demás usuarios. Lee [answer] y edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle. Saludos.